# How to determine probability of an outcome when the number of tries is variable.

Tags: probability

Given a known probability of an event being successful, how do you calculate the odds of at least one successful outcome when the number of times you can attempt is determined by a separate dice roll.

For example:  I know the probability of a favorable outcome on dice X is "P".      I first roll a six sided dice. That dice roll determines the number times I can roll dice X.  What is the probability that I will have at least one successful roll of dice X as a function of "P"?

Comment: You're looking for the law of total probability: $$P(A)=P(A\mid \text{head})P(\text{head})+P(A\mid \text{tails})P(\text{tails})$$ is what it would look like if the first die were a coin flip instead.

Comment: That would be $~\mathsf P(\text{at least one success}) ~=~1-\tfrac 16\sum_{k=1}^6 \mathsf P(\text{no success}\mid k\text{ tries})~$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the outcome of first dice roll is $k(1 \le k \ge 6$) each with probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

P(atleast 1 success)= 1-P(no success)

P(atleast 1 success) = P(k=1)*(1-P(no success with 1 throws)) + P(k=2)*(1-P(no success with 2 throws))+...6 terms

Since P(k=1)=P(k=2)=...=P(k=6)=1/6

Hence
P(atleast 1 success) = $\frac{1}{6} \sum_{k=1}^6$ (1-P(no success with k throws))

Thus the required answer is:
P(atleast 1 success) = $\frac{1}{6} \sum_{k=1}^6$ $(1-(1-p)^k$)
where $p$ is probability of favorable outcome given in question.

Comment: So, if instead of rolling one six sided dice, I use two three-sided dice to determine the number of of times to roll Dice X the solution would be P(atleast 1 success) = (1/9)*( (1-(1-p)^2) + 2*(1-(1-p)^3) + 3*(1-(1-p)^4)+ 2*(1-(1-p)^5) + (1-(1-p)^6))?

Answer (score 0):

P(desired outcome from N rolls) will be P(desired outcome from 1 roll)^N if you want each roll to satisfy a given condition.

P(at least 1 * desired outcome from N rolls) will be 1-P(not desired outcome)^N.

P(at least M * desired outcome from N rolls, $N \geq M$) will be 
$1-\sum_{b=0}^{M-1} {N \choose b} \left(\frac {1} {P(desired outcome)}\right)^N$

Answer (score -1):

1. If you roll the X die $k$ times, the probability of *failing* on all $k$ times  is $(1-p)^k$.
2. Hence the probability of succeeding at least once in $k$ tries is $1-(1-p)^k$. (because succeeding at least once and failing every time are complementary events.)
3. Because the initial die roll is independent of the X die roll, their probabilities multiply. The probability of succeeding when you roll a six-sided die then roll your X die that many times is:

   $$\sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{1}{6}\times \left[1-(1-p)^k\right] = 1-\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^6(1-p)^k$$
4. The geometric sum formula states that $\sum_{k=1}^n q^k = \frac{q(1-q^n)}{1-q}$.  In our case, this means that the overall probability of success with a $n=6$ sided die and $q=(1-p)$ geometric probability is:
   $$1-\frac{1}{6}\frac{(1-p)(1-(1-p^6))}{p},$$ which, if you like, is just the polynomial
   $$\Pr(p) = -\frac{1}{6}\left(p^6 - 7p^5 + 21 p^4 -35 p^3 + 35 p^2 - 21 p^1 \right)$$
5. As an example, when $p=\frac{1}{2}$ (X is a two-sided coin), the probability is around 0.83. When $p=\frac{1}{6}$ (X is another six-sided die), the probability is around 0.45.